# Set grid linetype as dash in C# Chart Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, mschart

I tried

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
```

but is not working.

The complete code for setting chart control is as below.The grid line becomes wider after my setting for LineDashStyle.

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.DashDotDot;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = 3600;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 3600;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 3600 * ((int)m / 3600 + 1);
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
Chart1.Series.Add("Latitude");
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Epoch[h]";
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.TitleFont = new Font("TimesNewRoman", 10);
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Width = 45;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Height = 30;
Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(time,rms_x);  
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Latitude[m]";
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.TitleFont = new Font("TimesNewRoman", 10);
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.IsStaggered = false;

//Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Name = "Latitude";
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.X = 0;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Y = 0;
Chart1.Series[0].ChartArea = "Latitude";
```

Here is the picture I got.'LinshDashStyle' has been update to dash in the first figure and the second figure is before updating.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information? Is any error displayed? When are you trying to update the LineDashStyle?

Comment: yes, the grid line becomes wider.I've posted the complete code.

Comment: The code in the first two lines __works just fine__! If it doesn't for you there must be some other code that resets it. As it is it does just what it is supposed to. Do post an image of what you get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
txt_Report.Text += ts.ReadData(textBox1.Text, isChecked);
txt_Report.Text += ts.DrawGraph(chart1, textBox1.Text, isChecked);
```

Thanks for all of your answers and comments, and I finnaly found that I passed Chart to an object to set its property is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the last line to your code and tell us the results.

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
```